# Show that the set of all even permutations in $G$ forms a subgroup of $G$.

Tags: group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups

> Show that if $G$ is any group of permutations, then the set of all even permutations in $G$ forms a subgroup of $G$.

I know that I need to show the closure, identity, and inverses properties hold. So I need to prove:

1) If $p$ and $q$ are even permutations, then so is $pq$.

2) Identity permutation is an even permutation

3) If $p$ is an even permutation, then so is $p^{-1}$

I am just unsure how to go about setting up each proof. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: How you set this up depends on what definition you use for "even permutation".

Comment: If $G\subset S_n$ for some $n$, since $A_n$ is a subgroup of $S_n$, $A_n\cap G$ is still a subgroup

Comment: @Alphago that assumes knowledge that $A_n$ is itself a group, which seems to be at least part of the point of the exercise to prove.

Comment: I see. From the content of OP, in fact this question can be about that $A_n$ is a group

Answer (score 5):

Let $E$ be the set of even permutations in $G$ (which is presumably a group of permutations).

Let $p$ and $q$ be elements of $E$.

Check to see if $pq^{-1}$ is also an element of $E$.  (Note: this checks all three conditions simultaneously).

A permutation is called an even permutation if its expression as a product of disjoint cycles has an even number of even-length cycles.

Alternatively, a permutation is called an even permutation if it can be written as a product of an even number of transpositions.

These two definitions can be seen to be equivalent.  The second seems a bit more useful here.

So, let $p=p_1p_2\cdots p_{2k}$ and $q=q_1q_2\cdots q_{2j}$ be a representation of $p$ and $q$ as a product of transpositions.

We have that $q^{-1}=q_{2j}q_{2j-1}\cdots q_2q_1$ since transpositions are self inverses.

Thus, $pq^{-1} = p_1p_2\cdots p_{2k}q_{2j}\cdots q_2q_1$ is indeed a product of an even number of transpositions.  Furthermore, $pq^{-1}$ is an element of $G$ since $p$ and $q$ (and thus $q^{-1}$) are elements of $G$ and $G$ is closed under products and inverses.

Thus $pq^{-1}\in E$, implying that the identity is an element of $E$ (by taking $p=q$), that it is closed under inverse (by taking $p=id$), and that it is closed under products (by taking $q^{-1}$ instead of $q$) and $E$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Comment: I think it should be "even number of even-length cycles.".

Comment: @DavitS you are correct.  I must have not been paying attention at the time.  Thankfully, since the proof was written using the definition of even in terms of the number of transpositions, the proof itself did not need to be corrected.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: consider the following map
$$\operatorname{sgn}(p)=\begin{cases}1,\, p\,\text{even};\\-1,\,p\,\text{odd}.\end{cases}$$
Show that it is a homomorphism from $G$ to $\{\pm1\}$. What's it's kernel?